# Json to case class with Option[Long]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Consider this case class

```
case class Location(val name: String, val id: Option[Long] = None)
```

I can write a "toJson" like so:

```
implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "id").write[Option[Long]]
    ) (unlift(Location.unapply))
```

but I am struggling with a "fromJson":

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String]
    ) (Location.apply _, None)
```

Explanation: The id should actually be set by the persistence layer, so I don't want to provide it manually.

I also tried:

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "id").read[Option[Long]]
    ) (Location.apply _)
```

but sadly then I get:

> No Json deserializer found for type Option[Long]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

Do I really need to create an implicit for that as well?

How come this works (as in: compiles)? I ask because it is absolutely trivial to humans, yet suddenly there is an implicit and it compiles. Not sure if this makes sense at all though, but I fear not

```
implicit val optionalLongReads: Reads[Option[Long]] = (
    (JsPath \ "optional").read[Option[Long]]
    )
```

**edit:** definitely makes no sense.

If I send `curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type:application/json" --data '{"name": "Gondor", "id": "2"}' localhost:9000` I get:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Content-Length: 8029
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Date: Sat, 08 Oct 2016 21:49:51 GMT

I cannot leave id empty either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Framework supports `Option` field out of the box.

You must use `readNullable[Long]` instead of `read[Option[Long]]`.

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[Long]
)(Location.apply _)
```

You can also use `writeNullable[Long]` in your `locationWrites`.

With `write[Option[Long]]` resulting json will contains `id` field set to `null` in case `id` is `None`. With `writeNullable[Long]` `id` field won't be present at all for `None` case:

```
val location = Location("Gondor", None)

// locationWrites with (JsPath \ "id").write[Option[Long]]
{
   "name":"Gondor",
   "id":null
}

// locationWrites with (JsPath \ "id").writeNullable[Long]
{
   "name":"Gondor"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that json lib doesn't support `Option` directly, try this:

```
implicit def readOption[T](implicit inner: Reads[T]): Reads[Option[T]] = inner.map(Some.apply).orElse(Reads.pure(None))
```

Apparently they do support it, try this:

```
(JsPath \ "id").nullable[Long]
```

yay dsls I guess.

Or use a more advanced json library, e.g. http://argonaut.io/ + https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless or https://travisbrown.github.io/circe/

Answer (score 0):

data which you are sending is "id": "2" , it is string. If you want to send Long, I think try "id": 2

Answer (score 0):

Play json supports automatic generation of serialization/deserialization functions for case classes out of the box, just use `Json.format` which automatically creates the needed `Reads` and `Writes`. Put it in the companion object for your case class.

```
case class Location(val name: String, val id: Option[Long] = None)

object Location {
  implicit val locationFormat = Json.format[Location]
}
```

Then use:

```
val withId = """{"name":"Bob","id":1234}"""
val withoutId = """{"name":"Charlie"}"""

val bob = Json.parse(withId).as[Location]
println(bob)
// Location(Bob,Some(1234))

val charlie = Json.parse(withoutId).as[Location]
println(charlie)
// Location(Charlie,None)
```

Comment: Uff... why are there these pages then: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonHttp (there are more pages). It makes sense, but...

Comment: You are right, the docs should mention `format` more prominently. I have found it is all you need most of the time.